# Name of an specific kind of simple roots

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology, roots

Is there a name for a simple root $p$ of a real-valued function $f \in \mathcal{C}^2(\Omega)$ (i.e., $f(p) = 0$ and $f'(p) \neq 0$) that **also** satisfies $f''(p) \neq 0$?

Is there a short name for such a root? I'm writing a paper and I'd like to refer to it in the title.

Comment: As far as I know, there are few circumstances where the second derivative at a root matters. And I have never heard of a "non-inflection" point. One could risk "curved" or "parabolic" root vs. "flat" or "straight" or "linear" root, but I don't think this would be well understood.

Comment: The thing is that I constructed a method with the second derivative as a denominator. I liked the "non-inflection" expression. Thanks for your comments, Ives.

Comment: I think the clearest thing would be to say "$p$ is a zero of $f$ and is not an inflection point." The term "non-inflection" sounds strange to me, and I might not understand it if I read it.